# How do I connect to link-local IPv6 with WMI/COM?

Tags: python, winapi, wmi

I'm trying to do some v4 network configuration of host A, from host B. Because using WMI over v4 would be a catch-22, I want to use link-local v6 to make my connection.

COM has, apparently, supported IPv6 since at least 2003. It seems that link-local was forgotten.

The confusing thing is this: if host A has working IPv4 (yes, 4), this works (in Python):

```
>>> c = wmi.WMI('fe80::c0af:e3e1:8383:ddc7%17', user='Administrator', password='blabla')
>>>
```

However, when I remove the v4 address from A's interface, or replace it with an address that host B can't connect to, the call above fails, reporting "The object exporter specified was not found". Interestingly, netstat on host A does show a connection attempt.

Additional info:

- Windows telnet.exe accepts the fe80-address, with and without %17, and connects to port 135 just fine.
- Python's socket.socket.connect does the same.

Any hints?

SOLVED: it appears WMI does some kind of callback-connection, and it can't cope with link local v6 in that scenario. Escalating to MS support.

Comment: could you post your solution as an answer below and mark it as the accepted one?

Comment: Heh. I actually looked for the 'answer' button before but totally glossed over it. Will fix.

Comment: Oh, I understand, it happens to me a lot :) And I find this "feature" of forced waiting really a bit annoying, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out whatever weird callback mechanism WMI does to get two-way communication going, cannot cope with link-local addressing. I'm escalating to Microsoft support.

UPDATE: I have discussed the issue with MS Support. As it turns out, the default settings for Windows Firewall block link-local name resolution, and WMI requires working name resolution.

Enabling the allow-rule for 'Network Discovery (LLMNR-UDP-In)' on the machine you are connecting to, makes everything work correctly. Apparently the issue is not some connect back, but WMI insisting on connecting to a named endpoint. Or something.